# Latency caused by ACPI.sys

Tags: windows-10, laptop, latency, acpi

(Specs below)

A few weeks ago, I started having problems with **latency**; all of a sudden audio and video **weren't synchronised** anymore and there were/was a lot of **stutters and crackling** (EDIT: my CPU usage isn't high - between 20 and 50% - as opposed to other persons who had a similar problem). Using DPClatency (consistent over 5000 microseconds) and Latencymon I discovered it was caused by **ACPI.sys**, which is very unspecific. I tried a lot of things including:

- updating all drivers (even those not connected to ACPI.sys)
- doing all proposed Windows updates
- disabling drivers (LAN, battery,...)
- doing a RAM check
- updating my BIOS

Nothing works, even though this last idea of updating the BIOS seemed to work for a bit; but the problem still returned. It usually starts about an hour after I boot my notebook, and doesn't stop until I reboot again. It makes no difference if I'm on battery power or on AC, nor if I idle or use it intensely. Any help on the subject is greatly appreciated, since it's driving me nuts.

Thanks a lot!

Specs:

- HP 15-d008ed notebook-pc (ENERGY STAR) - Model number F7T39EA
- Windows 10 Home Edition (updated from Windows 8.1 a few months ago)
- CPU Type: 4x Intel Pentium III Xeon, 2000 MHz
- DirectX: 4.09.00.0904 (DirectX 9.0c)
- Graphic card: Intel(R) HD Graphics
- Audio adapter: High Definition Audio Controller [NoDB]
- Network adapter: Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
- Network adapter: Realtek RTL8188EE 802.11 bgn Wi-Fi Adapter
- Battery: Microsoft AC Adapter 10.0.14393.0
- Battery: Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery 10.0.14393.0

(those are what I think the most important specs; I have all details saved if necessary)

Browsers: Chrome 54.0.2840.71 or Firefox 49.0.1

I use Wi-fi, almost never Ethernet cable

K.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [High CPU usage by "System" and "System interrupts" (caused by ACPI.sys)](http://superuser.com/questions/1135273/high-cpu-usage-by-system-and-system-interrupts-caused-by-acpi-sys)

Comment: Might be, indeed. I don't have that high CPU usage though...

Comment: I don't understand the instructions that you gave there @magicandre1981 ; which driver do you mean when you say "  
have you tried to go back to the standard MS storage driver?" I didn't think it had something to do with storage. Also: installing RST seems like overkill...

Comment: in the topic I talk about the Intel RST driver. have you checked all other points from my answer not the comments to the other user?

Comment: Oh, of course. I tried most of it, like updating BIOS and checking the fan/CPU temperature etc. I can't think of anything being wrong with my battery (keeps its charge etc.), but I found a way of working around the problem: I noticed it stops when I put it in sleep mode, so that's way better than restarting each time. I'll just keep searching some more, but  already thanks for the help!

Comment: reset the used powerplan of windows, maybe you changed a setting. Have you replaced the DVD drive with a caddy to use a 2nd HDD?