# System and compressed memory and system interrupts takes 40% of the cpu

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, cpu-usage

I searched a lot about this online and couldn't find a solution, I turned off fast startup as many answers have suggested. But it didn't work , 
The problem happened after I connected a secondary hard drive to my laptop removing the dvd drive , whenever I remove the secondary hard drive , above processes act normal. I have a SSD as my primary drive , the **problem happens only when the secondary drive is connected** , I desperately need a solution since this is killing my computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known issue. To use a hdd in the DVD slot, you used a HDD caddy. In some cases you get a high CPU usage caused by the ACPI.sys driver.

You have to look if your caddy has a jumper and if yes, change the position of the jumper.

[image]

[This fixes the CPU usage](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/172738-on-optical-bay-hd-caddy-adapters-for-laptops/#comment-1086063). If you don't have a jumper, buy a caddy which has such a jumper.

Comment: Totally fixed the issue instantly! Thank you very much , we need more people like you in this planet. :-)

Comment: But what does the jumper do, technically?

Comment: @grawity I'm guess, to make it master or slave drive ?

Comment: @grawity this "Device Attention" pin which is used in Win8 for some purpose: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn614034(v=vs.85).aspx . I thinl the jumper just turns this off

Comment: @lasan That does not exist in SATA.