# How can I disable a particular interrupt in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, performance, interrupts

It seems to be caused by the SSD disk installed instead of an optical drive, in the relevant questions about Linux the suggested solution is like:

```
echo "disable" > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe13
```

How can I disable such an interrupt in Windows?

Comment: Whats the intention behind this?

Comment: This interrupt happens too often, so there is some CPU load even when my laptop is idle. The command above helped for Ubuntu running on it,

Comment: you need to [change the jumper on the caddy to fix the ACPI interrupt issue](https://superuser.com/a/1152438/174557)