# ACPI.sys high CPU usage

Tags: cpu, power, acpi, ntoskrnl.exe

i need help to identify what i causing this. i have a new HP Omen 17 got it for a month now and somehow the laptop keeps one core busy the whole time. i appreciate any help!! thank you!

i updated bios (F.13)
tried unplugging HDD
installed clean windows (i think it was good then, but something happend...)
tried the stuff with intel rapid store drive and lan configuration..

i have an kaby lake 7700hq 2.8ghz - 3.8ghz (running allways in turbo since this process keeps the cpu from downgrading)
1070gtx 
16gb ram
1 tb hdd and 512 mv.2 ssd

[image: CPU Usage]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [High CPU usage by "System" and "System interrupts" (caused by ACPI.sys)](https://superuser.com/questions/1135273/high-cpu-usage-by-system-and-system-interrupts-caused-by-acpi-sys)

Comment: see my [answer from here](https://superuser.com/a/1135317/174557). if you replaced the DVD drive with a HDD in a caddy, change the jumper position on the caddy

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. The trick is in the POWER SETTINGS.
Go to

> Power options → Edit power plan → Advanced power settings

Find and expand the PCIE setting.
Then set everything to OFF! (off meaning that POWER SAVING is off not that PICE will be off).
To be sure also set Wireless Adapter Setting to Maximum performance.