# High "System interrupt" CPU % in Windows 10 Task manager, linked to ACPI.sys, if and only if a serial port device is connected

Tags: windows, windows-10, cpu, serial-port, interrupts

I see a 20% "System interrupt" CPU usage in the Windows 10 task manager if and only if a device is connected to the PC with serial port.

[image]

With the "LatencyMon" tool, I can see this comes from ACPI.sys.

I am in the situation described by:

[High CPU usage by "System" and "System interrupts" (caused by ACPI.sys)](https://superuser.com/questions/1135273/high-cpu-usage-by-system-and-system-interrupts-caused-by-acpi-sys)

but more specifically this is linked to serial port: if I disconnect the device connected to the PC via serial port, the problem disappears.

Is there something to do:

- on the motherboard ?  (it is a KTQ87/Flex motherboard with Phoenix BIOS)
- in Windows 10 device manager ?
- I don't think there is something to do on the device connected by serial port itself, after all, serial communication is just high/low bits sent at a certain bitrate, there is no "configuration" except bitrate, number of stop-bits, etc.

?

Comment: “True” serial ports (as opposed to, say, USB adapters) use interrupts. Does your device send lots of data?

Comment: @DanielB Yes it sends hardware status a few times per second. So do you think that maybe it is normal and acceptable?

Comment: You may check, when the device is connected, what it looks like in Device Manager, and especially in Properties what driver it's using.

Comment: Ok I'll report this @harrymc.