# Dell XPS Audio Dropouts - ACPI.sys Latency

Tags: windows-10, audio, dell-xps, acpi, dpc

As documented across the internet, many users of Dell XPS laptops encounter a problem of high DPC latency, which manifests as clicks & popping sounds when audio is played on the system. For these users, there is one main culprit - the ACPI.sys driver. This is confirmed when I use LatencyMon to diagnose the cause.

After having had to replace the motherboard in my XPS 15 9550, I started experiencing this issue. I have tried many troubleshooting steps, one I have not yet tried is the last comment of [this Super User post](https://superuser.com/questions/1135273/high-cpu-usage-by-system-and-system-interrupts-caused-by-acpi-sys), outlined by user gl-:

> I was nearly ready to just overwrite a prior backup image, but with
> nothing to lose this worked:
>
> - Device Manager -> View -> Devices by Connection
> - find some juicy root nodes (eg. PCI(e) stuff, USB 3.0 controllers, HD controllers) and nuke them, taking everything below with them.
> - Don't necessarily delete their drivers if asked (unless desperate).
>   reboot.
>
> Bingo, pretty much all my hardware was re-detected on next boot, and the problem went away. I can only assume that it wasn't so much a single rogue driver, as some corruption in my driver setup (or a specific driver's setup) generally.

My question(s) are as follows:

- By 'nuke', do they mean 'Uninstall' the drivers?
- What exactly do they mean by 'root nodes', and how do I choose the ones they are talking about?
- What's the worst thing that could happen when uninstalling the things they are talking about?

I am grateful for any assistance I may get. Thank you

Comment: Please put all steps in your question using the [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1798439/edit) button underneath, not in comments.